# Need help for HTML and CSS codes ~

Tags: html, css

This is the image I want to make the : Journal Timeline and Gallery Text on the middle please help me guys... how to make it center align

[image]

```css
#pages ul{
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border:5px solid;
    border-radius:15px;
    width: 700px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-color: white;
}
#pages ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 45px;
}
#pages ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.home_icon{
    padding-top: 3.5px;
}
```

thats the code for CSS

```
<div id="pages">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img class = "home_icon" src="img/home_icon.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JOURNAL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TIMELINE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please I need the explanation and codes :) thank you

Comment: Please explain your question better. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: "Plz give me teh codez"  is generally not welcome on SO. Without explanation of what is unclear for you wnad where you are stuck this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:middle;` in your `<li>`'s CSS:

```
#pages ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 45px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/RMLEw/4/)